# How to read contact in windows phone 7 programatically using silverlight and c#?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

How to read contact in windows phone 7 programatically using silverlight and c#?

Answer (score 2):

Right now you only get access to one contact at a time through the EmailAddressChooserTask API. There's no way to read the entire contact list.

Comment: Thanks for reply.Can you please send me a code example.it will help me a lot.Many Thanks

Comment: The EmailAddressChooserTask class is simple enough. Google for it.

Comment: public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{PhoneNumberChooserTask phoneNumberChooserTask;
public MainPage()
{InitializeComponent();
phoneNumberChooserTask = new PhoneNumberChooserTask();
phoneNumberChooserTask.Completed += new EventHandler<PhoneNumberResult>(phoneNumberChooserTask_Completed);
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {try{phoneNumberChooserTask.Show();}catch (System.InvalidOperationException ex)
{ } }
void phoneNumberChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhoneNumberResult e)
{if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK){textBox1.Text =e.PhoneNumber;}}
}

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows phone 7.0 you can only read in one contact at a time. using either the `EmailAddressChooserTask` or `PhoneNumberChooserTask` like so, you can do the same with `EmailAddressChooserTask`:

```
private PhoneNumberChooseTask myPhoneChooserTask;

public MainPage()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   myPhoneChooserTask = new PhoneNumberChooseTask ();
   myPhoneChooserTask.Completed += (o, e) => 
   {
      if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
         //Here means the phone is chosen successfully. you can access the phone number with e.PhoneNumber
      else
         //Here means the phone is not chosen
   }
   myPhoneChooserTask.Show(); //Show contact list for choosing
}
```

However, with the windows OS 7.1 you can read in all contacts by using the contacts search with an empty string like so.. taken from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286416(v=vs.92).aspx

```
private void ButtonContacts_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Contacts cons = new Contacts();

    //Identify the method that runs after the asynchronous search completes.
    cons.SearchCompleted += new EventHandler<ContactsSearchEventArgs>(Contacts_SearchCompleted);

    //Start the asynchronous search.
    cons.SearchAsync(String.Empty, FilterKind.None, "Contacts Test #1");
}

void Contacts_SearchCompleted(object sender, ContactsSearchEventArgs e)
{
    //Do something with the results.
    MessageBox.Show(e.Results.Count().ToString());
}
```

Good luck!